# Need Help regarding Jmeter requirement

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Am new to Jmeter and working on below Jmeter requirement. Can anybody please help me how to implement below scenario to get the correct output in detail, Your valuable suggestions are highly appreciated.

Assume i have 5 URL's and tested response time by applying load for 10 concurrent users and the response time as generated as below.

```
      URL1  URL2 URL3 URL4 URL5
```

User1     1500  1800    1900    2200    1500

User2   1800    2500    2300    2400    1500

User3   2500    1800    2600    2300    2500

User4   3500    1600    2400    1300    2600

User5   1700    1300    2500    2300    2400

User6   1000    1600    2600    1600    1400

User7   1600    1200    2500    1700    3000

User8   2300    2500    2600    2700    1900

User9   1900    1800    1700    1400    1600

User10  2100    1500    1400    1900    2600

---

```
     19900  17600 22500  19800   21000
```

Total Response time for each URL for 10 Users(mili seconds)

---

```
      1990    1760    2250   1980    2100
```

Average response time for 10 users (mili seconds)

---

My requirement is, the pages which are loaded in less than 2 seconds (i,e 2000 ms) set the status to 1 (Pass) and those pages which are loaded in more than 2 seconds set the status to 0 (Fail) for 10 concurrent users.

```
Average Response time for 10 users      Status         (pass/fail)
          URL1                           1900             1
          URL2                           1760             1
          URL3                           2250             0
          URL4                           1980             1
          URL5                           2100             0
                                        --------------------
                                                          3
```

Than calculate the percentage as below.

Percentage=Count of Status / Total number of URL.

Count of status-3    AND    Total number of URL-5.

3/5= 0.6 (I,e 60% of pages are loaded within less than 2 seconds for 10 concurrent users.)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not made to do the job for you, only to help you when you face a particular issue. First start watching videos on how JMeter works, read documentation, try and then ask a precise question.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

1. Create new test suite project that is executed [by Maven](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com) ( the
   [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin) isnt quite ready yet).
2. Add 5 new thread groups, 1 for each url.  (make sure thread group names have no spaces in the name or step 6 wont look right)
3. Edit the threads and loops value you want on each thread group.
4. In each thread group, add whichever http samplers you need.
5. Hook up the [jmeter maven analysis plugin](https://github.com/afranken/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin) in your maven pom.xml
6. Execute your maven job and then look at the generated reports.